# Type mismatch on values: 'runtime error 13'

Tags: vba, excel

I was running my macro perfectly then all of a sudden the macro started to show *runtime error 13' Type mismatch* and I can't figure it out. The part that's always getting highlighted is:

```
  If Cells(x, "E") >= Num1 And Cells(x, "E") <= Num2 Then
```

and I think I coded it correctly because my other macros are coded that way but for some reason this is not working.

```
Sub PPM()

Dim RawData As Worksheet
Dim MatchData As Worksheet


Set MatchData = Worksheets("MATCH")
Set Pastesheet = Worksheets("PASTE")

Pastesheet.Select
Pastesheet.Range("$A$3:$F$5000").Clear

MatchData.Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Set Num1 = MatchData.Range("$I$3")
Set Num2 = MatchData.Range("$K$3")

Dim x As Long

For x = 6 To 5000

If Cells(x, "E") >= Num1 And Cells(x, "E") <= Num2 Then

 Cells(x, "A").Resize(, 6).Copy

Pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial _
xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


    End If

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Pastesheet.Select

MsgBox "Search Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `x` when the error first happens?

Comment: Similarly - what's the value of `Cells(x, "E")` when you see the error?

Comment: A Shot in the dark: Your cell `Cells(x, "E")` has a formula error like `#N/A` or similar

Comment: I actually figured it out, some of the cells in range E had a #N/A in it and had to add a formula to format that, THANKS GUYS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always declare the types of your variables. It makes it so much easier to debug. Currently you're comparing ranges using a numeric comparison:

```
Set Num1 = MatchData.Range("$I$3")
Set Num2 = MatchData.Range("$K$3")
...
If Cells(x, "E") >= Num1 And Cells(x, "E") <= Num2 Then
```

VBA helps you in that it will compare numbers if the cells contain numbers - however, it will fail gruesomely if the cells contain text because the <= and => operators are undefined for strings.

I would suggest something like this. First a helper function:

```
Private Function GetInt(rng as Range) As Integer
   On Error Resume Next
   GetInt = CInt(rng.Value)
End Function
```

Then change your code to:

```
Dim Num1 As Integer, Num2 As Integer
Num1 = GetInt(MatchData.Range("$I$3"))
Num2 = GetInt(MatchData.Range("$K$3"))
...
If GetInt(Cells(x, "E")) >= Num1 And GetInt(Cells(x, "E")) <= Num2 Then
```

Now you're code will always be safe from unexpected data in your cells. Note that I assume two things:

- It is alright for the code to assume a value of 0, if the cells contain text
- You're cells contain integers. If they contain decimal numbers, you should change the helper function to this:

```
Private Function GetDouble(rng as Range) As Double
   On Error Resume Next
   GetDouble = CDbl(rng.Value)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if  `MatchData.Range("$I$3"),MatchData.Range("$K$3")`and the cells from `MatchData.Range("E6")` to `MatchData.Range("E5000")` are numeric. I hope it will help you.